# Wrong DLL calling convention using VB6

Tags: opencv, vb6

I'm trying to create a window using OpenCV with VB6.

The [original C++ code](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html) is this:

```
C: IplImage* cvCreateImage(CvSize size, int depth, int channels)
```

So in VB6 I declare the following function:

```
Private Declare Function cvCreateImage CDecl Lib "opencv_core220.dll" (ByRef uSize As CvSize, ByVal uDepth As Long, ByVal uChannels As Long) As Long

Private Type CvSize
    width As Long
    height As Long
End Type
```

And then I call like this:

```
Dim nSize As CvSize
nSize.width = 1024
nSize.height = 768

Dim l8 As Long
Dim l3 As Long
l8 = 8
l3 = 3

Dim lDisplayImage As Long
lDisplayImage = cvCreateImage(nSize, l8, l3)
```

Looks perfectly fine to me, but VB6 tells me:

> Wrong DLL calling convention.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: VB6 is from, what?, 1998?  Why are you still using such an outdated language?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I have a really big monster. I'm converting it since 6 years, but still not finished, so I'm still stuck with VB6.

Comment: @tmighty -- By default, the calling convention for C++ is `_cdecl`.  I have not used VB6 in years, but I believe the calling convention is `_stdcall`.  Google what calling conventions are, as that is a big topic -- in a nutshell it determines how parameters are passed to the function and how the `return` from such functions are handled.  If the calling conventions do not match between the caller and the callee, you will get errors like this.